# how can i get the date full time of specific string format

Tags: android, datetime

I have an API contains string date with this format "/Date(1527677209864)/", how can I get the date and time to be used in Android app

Comment: OffsetMinutes =0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date) with the epoch number as a parameter in the constructor.

First you have to strip `/Date(` and `)/` from the string, this you can do with regex.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D+([0-9]+)\\D+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("/Date(1527677209864)/");

if (matcher.matches()) {
   long timestamp = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
   Date actualDate = new Date(timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that 1527677209864 value is a timestamp, right?
Try this function:

```
public static String getDateAndTime(@NotNull Context context, long timestamp) {

        Date date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(getTimeFormat(context), Locale.getDefault());

        return df.format(date);

    }
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prefix `/Date(` and suffix `)/`. Use the result to initialize a `java.util.Date`.

```
String dt = "/Date(1527677209864)/";
dt = dt.substring(6, dt.indexOf(")/"));
long timestamp = Long.parseLong(dt);
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
```

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format this date to your required format.

Answer (score 0):

We have to filter the `timeInMillis` value from the string and convert it to `long` so that we can use or set it in `calendar` and get the `date` object.

```
Date convertToDate(String input) {

    // input = "/Date(1527677209864)/";

    String timeString = input.substring(6, input.length() - 2);

    Long time = Long.parseLong(timeString);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Then we can format the date object to string according to our desire patter or format.

```
String convertDateToString(Date date, String pattern) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
String jsonDate = "/Date(1527677209864)/";
        jsonDate = jsonDate.substring(6, 13);
        int unix_timestamp = Integer.parseInt(jsonDate);
        Date date = new Date(unix_timestamp);
```